# List of RSpec's generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm looking for a comprehensive list of **RSpec's generators** to easily generate specs for controllers, models, helpers, and so on. The only one I've found is:

> rails g integration_test *name*

that saves a spec inside the spec/requests folder.

Answer (score 13):

- controller
- helper
- install
- integration
- mailer
- model
- observer
- scaffold
- view

example usage:

```
rails g rspec:integration events
--> create  spec/requests/events_spec.rb
```

Answer (score 3):

All the rspec-rails generators can be found at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/tree/master/lib/generators/rspec You'll have to dig around in the code a little to see what they do, but they are well organized so it shouldn't be too much of a pain.

There's also a [short readme on the generators](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/features/Generators.md) which basically says that they are run automatically when you run one of the standard Rails generators (rails g model User):

> If you type script/rails generate, the only RSpec generator you'll
>   actually see is rspec:install. That's because RSpec is registered with
>   Rails as the test framework, so whenever you generate application
>   components like models, controllers, etc, RSpec specs are generated
>   instead of Test::Unit tests.

Comment: I know that they are run automatically when I run one Rails generator, but what about if I want to run them outside this scope? Looking at your link, I'm not able to find somehting useful.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that you can run `rails g rspec:model NAME` or whatever other generator you need. The first link I posted has a list of the generators (each directory is a different one)